# Why is the Array Modifier offsetting this object by 1 in the Z axis when the Z field says 0?

Tags: modifiers, objects

The screenshot below says it all, really. The object is offset in both the X and the Z axes, though only the X axis says 1. No other modifiers are on it, no constraints, no locked axes, and I can't think of anything else that would affect this. How can I make it stop doing this?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a problem with the object's origin point. Try pressing Shift + Ctrl + Alt + C while the object is selected and click on "Origin to Geometry" to see what happens.

Comment: Nope. I tried it, and the origin is now in the center of it, but it does the same thing. :/

Comment: What happens when you set the X value to 0?

Comment: It snaps onto itself like you'd expect. When i set just Z to 1, it moves down by one and along the X axis by 0.5. (??)

Comment: Oh hey - when i clear rotation, it turns 90 degrees around the Z axis and 45 around the Y axis... so i guess i have to put it in the position i want and make that the 'cleared' position?

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl+A and then clicking on Scale, and then repeating that for Rotation. It might clear those issues up

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks. If you want to quickly write that up as an answer, i'll accept it and vote it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have rotations and scaling settings that are interfering with the Array modifier.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> with the object selected in Object Mode and click on *Scale* in the menu that comes up to set the default scale of your object to its current size, and repeat this with *Rotation* to set the current rotation of your object to the default rotation.

Comment: please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data